# Unexpected Results from \dolistloop

Tags: loops, etoolbox, csv

Given `\def\CSVList{a,b,c}`, using `\dolistloop{\CSVList}` does not seem to process the `\CSVList` as expected:

[image]

Perhaps I am not understanding how `\dolistloop` is supposed to work, but this example is pretty much straight from the documentation:

[image]

### Question:

- How can I use `\dolistloop` to get the desired results?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\CSVList{a,b,c}%

\begin{document}
    \par\noindent
    \verb|\dolistloop| results:
    \begin{itemize}
        \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1.}%
        \dolistloop{\CSVList}%
    \end{itemize}
    
    \par\noindent
    Expected results:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a.
        \item b.
        \item c.
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know anything about the second part of the question, but the first one can be answered by switching to the (unfortunately rather clumsy IMHO) procedure of building up the list that is described in the manual. I am not an expert on this, and do almost all my lists with `\pgffor` (which of course also has drawbacks), so I will be happy to delete my answer if a real answer by shows up. Anyway, this is the procedure that works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\CSVList}{}
\listadd{\CSVList}{a}
\listadd{\CSVList}{b}
\listadd{\CSVList}{c}

\begin{document}
    \par\noindent
    \verb|\dolistloop| results:
    \begin{itemize}
        \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1.}%
        \dolistloop{\CSVList}%
    \end{itemize}

    \par\noindent
    Expected results:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a.
        \item b.
        \item c.
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The initialisation procedure could be shortened to `\newcommand{\CSVList}{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\CSVList}{a,b,c}`. Whether that is practical for the intended use case is another question...

Answer (score 5):

`etoolbox` has two concepts of lists: (1) Internal lists built by `\listadd` and friends and iterated over with `\dolistloop`, `\forlistloop` and friends. And (2) CSV lists that have no building commands and are iterated over with `\docsvlist` and `\forcsvlist`. Usually when the `etoolbox` manual talks about lists, the internal lists are meant.

[marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450636/35864) shows how to use internal lists (my preferred solution here), so this answer will show how to use CSV lists.

`\docsvlist\CSVList` does not work due to expansion issues, so you need `\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\CSVList}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\CSVList{a,b,c}%

\begin{document}
  \par\noindent
  \verb|\docsvlist| results:
  \begin{itemize}
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1.}%
    \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\CSVList}%
  \end{itemize}

  \par\noindent
  Expected results:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item a.
    \item b.
    \item c.
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: The screenshot shows two identical lists with points "a.", "b." and "c."]

Answer (score 1):

An `etoolbox` list is not a comma separated list. However, it's not difficult to input a comma separated list and transform it into an `etoolbox` list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\defineetoolboxlist}[2]{%
  \def\do##1{\listadd{#1}{##1}}%
  \docsvlist{#2}%
}
\defineetoolboxlist\CSVList{a,b,c}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\verb|\dolistloop| results:
\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1.}
\dolistloop{\CSVList}
\end{itemize}

\noindent
Expected results:
\begin{itemize}
\item a.
\item b.
\item c.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or `\forcsvlist{\listadd\CSVList}{a,b,c}`

Comment: @moewe Thanks, but this heavily depends on the implementation of `\forcsvlist`.

Comment: But doesn't everything at some point? ;-) This code is used in the `etoolbox` manual (p. 29), so I guess it should be fine and is intended to work.

Comment: @moewe Perhaps. However, the method in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450642/4427 is much neater, in my opinion. For instance, `\addtolist{CSVList}{a,b,c}` and `\addtolist{CSVList}{ a, b ,c}` are completely equivalent, whereas `etoolbox` is sensitive to spaces.