# How does \renewcommand immediately following a \begin{itemize} prevent missing \item error

Tags: lists, itemize

The `itemize` list below works fine. However, if I attempt to move the

```
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1.}
```

outside of the itemize, it results in a

> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

### Questions:

- Why does moving the `\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1.}` to the preamble result in the error
- How does having the `\renewcommand` there prevent this error?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\CSVList}{}
\listadd{\CSVList}{a}
\listadd{\CSVList}{b}
\listadd{\CSVList}{c}

\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1.}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1.}%
        \dolistloop{\CSVList}%
    \end{itemize}

%% -------------------- This results in the "missing \item" error.
%    \begin{itemize}
%        \dolistloop{\CSVList}%
%    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \do is used everywhere. You should redefine it only very locally.

Comment: Avoid `\dolistloop` and prefer `\forlistloop`, where you specify a handler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `\do` is used at the `\begin{document}` by the LaTeX kernel to make the `\@onlypreamble` commands throw an error when used outside the preamble.

The definition of `\document` contains:

```
\gdef\do##1{\global\let ##1\@notprerr}%
\@preamblecmds
\global\let \@nodocument \relax
\global\let\do\noexpand % <-- this causes the problem
```

so `\do` becomes `\noexpand` right after `\begin{document}`, so your `\newcommand` in the preamble has no effect.

If you put the `\renewcommand` inside the `itemize`, when the environment group ends, the previous definition of `\do` (`\noexpand`) is restored and this raises the `missing \item`.

If you move the `\renewcommand` outside the `itemize`, its new definition is kept until the second `itemize` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\CSVList}{}
\listadd{\CSVList}{a}
\listadd{\CSVList}{b}
\listadd{\CSVList}{c}

\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1.}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1.}%
        \dolistloop{\CSVList}%
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{itemize}
\show\do
        \dolistloop{\CSVList}%
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The console will show

```
> \do=\noexpand.
l.18 \show\do
```

Thus your `\do{a}` will do

```
\noexpand\item a
```

and the output will be, after the “missing `\item`” error, just

> abc

Much better is to define a specific handler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\CSVList}{}
\listadd{\CSVList}{a}
\listadd{\CSVList}{b}
\listadd{\CSVList}{c}

\newcommand*{\doCSV}[1]{\item #1.}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\forlistloop{\doCSV}{\CSVList}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

<sup>I have removed all superfluous `%` characters.</sup>

A different implementation, where the handler is built on the fly; the current item in the list is denoted by `#1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_if_exist:cF { l_grill_list_#1_clist }
   {
    \clist_new:c { l_grill_list_#1_clist }
   }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \clist_put_right:cn { l_grill_list_#1_clist } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\uselist}{mm}
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__grill_uselist:n { #2 }
  \clist_map_function:cN { l_grill_list_#1_clist } \__grill_uselist:n
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\addtolist{CSVList}{a}
\addtolist{CSVList}{b,c}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\uselist{CSVList}{\item #1.}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```